# Why is there unknown margin/padding in the box?

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me why is there unknown margin/padding appearing at the bottom of the box? Please see if you can look into this and help me. I also want image to be zoomed in initially and then in scale=1 just before rotation and after rotation, it would be zoomed in again.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #f9cf47;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box p {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.rotate-img {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: rotation;
  -webkit-animation: rotation 1s linear 1;
  -moz-animation: rotation 1s linear 1;
  animation: rotation 1s linear 1;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img class="rotate-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5804256/483779

Answer (score 0):

Because inside that box you have an inline element `img` which are aligned to `baseline` by default...So you will need to use `vertical-align: top` to the image to remove the gap...

If you apply `border` to that image instead of box, you will not see any gap...

Also you will need to play with some keyframe timing to achieve your result

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #f9cf47;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box p {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.rotate-img {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: rotation;
  animation: rotation 2s linear 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2);
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  66% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img class="rotate-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</div>
```